# ResultSet to ArrayList and proper way select information

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, arraylist, resultset

I have successfully called a Stored Procedure ("Users_info") from my java app, which returns a table that contains two columns: ("user" and "status").

```
CallableStatement proc_stmt = con.prepareCall("{call Users_info (?)}");

    proc_stmt.setInt(1, 1);
    ResultSet rs = proc_stmt.executeQuery();
```

I managed to get all the user names and their respective status ("0" for inactive and "1" for active) into a ArrayList using ResultSet.getString.

```
ArrayList<String> userName= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> userStatus= new ArrayList<String>();


    while ( rs.next() ) { 

        userName.add(rs.getString("user"));
        userStatus.add(rs.getString("CHKStatus_Id"));
    }
```

Database shows:

```
user        | status|
------------|--------
Joshua H.   | 1     |
Mark J.     | 0     |
Jonathan R. | 1     |
Angie I.    | 0     |
Doris S.    | 0     |
```

I want to find the best or most efficient way to separate the active users from the inactive users.

I can do this by comparing values using IF STATEMENTS, which, because of my limited knowledge in Java programming I think is not the most efficient way and maybe there is a better way that you guys can help me understand.

Thanks.

Comment: IF is very efficient  ! But why do you want to do this? If you only need the active users, then fetch only them from the database. If you want to show all users and mark the active, write a class `User` with 2 attributes (`name` and `state`) create the objects, and write them to ONE `List`...

Comment: I've been given the name of the stored procedure and what it returns, which I do not control. Your approach in the second part sounds good, I will try that.

Comment: ok, have a look: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2979739/learn-java/java-101-classes-and-objects-in-java.html